# Hyper-V not working on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I'm unable to start a virtual machine on my newly installed instance of Hyper-V on Windows 8. Here is the error message I'm getting:

[image: Could not find a usable certificate. Error: 'Element not found']

I've tried:

- Re-installing Hyper-V
- Restarting the Hyper-V service
- The steps listed [here](http://blog.jussipalo.com/2012/03/could-not-find-usable-certificate-error.html).
- Installing [kb967902](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967902) (couldn't install it)

Any ideas?

**Edit 1**

The error occurs for a single VM that was created through Hyper-V. The VM currently has no OS on it (because it's newly created).

This is the only VM on Hyper-V. I'm simply trying to install XP on a VM so I can do some IE 8 testing.

**Edit 2**

I've tried all the steps in @MystereMan's answer & comments up to and including a reinstall of  Hyper-V.

We've narrowed the problem down to a certificate not existing in `vmms\Personal\Certificates`.

**Edit 3**

> Host name found: OMS144.WORKGROUP Creating a new certificate using
>   **makecert.exe Error: Can't create the key of the subject
>   ('ac9fcedb-e695-4279-817d-fd1c98729dd6') Failed Unexpected Exception!**
>
> At C:\Users\OMS 144\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:44 char:9+         throw
>   “Certificate Not Found error. Check if makecert.exe is successful 
>   ...+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ At C:\Users\OMS
>   144\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:11 char:20+   0..100 | foreach { write-host
>   -ForegroundColor White   ((gv -ErrorAction Silen ...+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Certificate Not Found
>   error. Check if makecert.exe is successful or not

**Edit 4**

Certificate created successfully:

> vmms\Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates\OMS144.WORKGROUP

Error message persists.

Comment: Is it just this one specific VM, or does it do this for ANY VM?  Where/how did you create the VM? Have you rebooted the host since installing Hyper-V?

Comment: @techie007, see edit.

Comment: @JamesHill - Scrap the Virtual Machine and reinstall Windows XP on a new machine.  Microsoft provides free virtual machiens for IE testing.

Comment: @Ramhound - when you say a new windows xp machine, are you referring to a physical machine or a virtual machine? Also, when you say scrap it, do you mean delete it an create another VM? Where would the free ones from $MS come from for IE testing?

Comment: @JamesHill - They are on the Microsoft website.  Yes, I mean delete the current virtual machine file, create a new virtual machine, and reinstall Windows XP on it.  I must have missed where this was already newely created sounds like you have a hardware compatability problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, Virtualization is enabled in the bios. I'm running a new quad core Xeon E5. My hardware should support this. I disagree with your assessment.

Comment: Does [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/c3069d53-5b4a-4318-b6a7-371f60632181) help?

Comment: @harrymc, unfortunately not.

Comment: Here is [Microsoft resolution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971264?wa=wsignin1.0) to a similar problem (same error code) that you could try.

Comment: @harrymc, unfortunately not. I do not have SCVMM installed. This is a Windows 8 machine. The only software I have to manage the VM's is Hyper-V Manager. I did try to delete the certificates it mentioned...

Comment: Deleting the certificates is what I meant - so this doesn't work. Next try is described in [this article](http://virtualisationandmanagement.wordpress.com/2010/11/19/how-to-fix-the-unspecified-error-0x80004005-could-not-find-a-usable-certificate-windows-2008r2/), where you create the certificate yourself using a powershell script.

Comment: @harrymc, see edit 3. MakeCert failed. This is unreal!

Comment: Did you run it as administrator ?

Comment: Your problem is getting weirder. [This post](http://nerdwords.blogspot.fr/2008/01/makecertexe-error-can-create-key-of.html) might be useful regarding folder permissions. More explanations [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278381).

Comment: @harrymc, It was a permissions issue. The certificate has been created successfully, but I'm still receiving the same error!

Comment: Could you please update your post regarding the created certificate and in which store.

Comment: @harrymc, done.

Comment: James, you will need to give a better and much more detailed description of the actual state of the problem, with the commands that you have entered and the certificates you have in vmms and in Internet Options / Content / Certificates. I have gone as far as I can on the material at hand.

Comment: @harrymc, I'm afraid I can't offer any more information. As for the commands I've typed in - I've typed in everything exactly as the links you provided instructed.

Comment: Among other points, the info I asked for was to verify if you have a certificate in the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities container, self-signed and generated by the Remote Desktop Gateway service. If you do, export and remove it and restart both services (or better - reboot).

Comment: Check security options in bios

Comment: @ralu, can you elaborate? What security options?

Answer (score 3):

Hyper-V requires a CPU that supports Hardware Virtualization an it must be enabled in the BIOS.  Verify that your CPU supports this (download CPU-z and check).  Check the bios settings for virtualization support.

**EDIT:**

OK, this problem is probably because of an expired or corrupted certificate.  Follow these steps:

1. Open up a command prompt and type `Services.msc`.  Go to `Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management` and stop the service.
2. In the command prompt, type `mmc` and hit enter.  In the File menu, choose `Add/Remove Snap-in`, select Certificates and then Add.
3. In the next window select `Service Account` and Next. In the Select Computer select the default of `Local Computer` then Next.
4. Now under the Service Account drill down to the `Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management` and select it then Finish and OK.
5. Now in the left hand pane expand `Certificates`, `vmms\Personal` and highlight `Certificates`. In the right hand pane double click on the certificate, should show the Issued To as the host machine name.
6. On the General tab of the certificate at the bottom it should show Valid from and a starting and ending date. The problem is that the certificate has expired.
7. Now close the window for the certificate and then in the right hand pane right click and select delete.
8. Go back to the Services.msc and restart the `Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management` service.
9. Back to the MMC console and refresh the `Personal\Certificates` and you should see a new one there. Double click on it and verify the new valid dates.
10. To be able to access the VM's now you will either have to restart the VM or simply use the save state then start the VM back up.

Comment: Virtualization is enabled. I'm running a quad core Xeon E5. My hardware should support this.

Comment: @JamesHill - see the update

Comment: +1 for the effort/instructions. I get to step #5 before I can't go further. I have no certificates listed under `vmms\Personal`. The folder is empty.

Comment: @JamesHill - well, that's the problem.  Did you restart the service?  Did it generate a new certificate?  Did you reboot the computer after installing Hyper-V?

Comment: @JamesHill - Also, check under the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities for a certificate with the name of your computer.  Also, look under all the others, and delete any you find.  Also, did you disable UAC?  If so, that could be a problem.  Also run SFC /scannnow and if all else fails, try refreshing the install or doing a new clean install.